# Not able to override css

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class="dlrs">
    <div id="listItems">
        <div id="clrCode" class="colorBlock" 
             style="background-image: url("/media/images/orange.png"); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-          repeat;">
        </div>
        <span>0 pts ( > 20 min)</span>
        <ul id="dlrsList">
            <li id="itmDlrName">Crosstown Auto Centre</li>
            <li id="itmDlrName">Dartmouth Chrysler Jeep Dodge</li>
            <li id="itmDlrName">Grande Prairie Chrysler Jeep Dodge</li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dlrs {
    //display: inline-block;
    width: 630px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
    font-weight: @bldTxt;
    font-size: 14px;

    #listItems {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;

        span {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 16px;
            left: 20px;
        }

        #dlrsList {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: justify;
            /*float: left;
            width: 190px;
            margin-right: 14px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;*/
            #itmDlrName {
                padding: 0px;
                list-style-type:disc;
                position: relative;                
                left: 20px;                
                max-width: 160px;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is I am  trying to get bullets on my `li` elements, what happening is there is an CSS setting in my file that says

```
ol, ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

I had increased the specificity by using id as above in my CSS and even tried `!important`, but still I am not able to override it, if I remove the `none` property in FireBug and give `disc` property for `li` then it works.

Is there any work around ?

Comment: First of all you have same IDs on your list items...

Comment: Couldn't help myself, not over ride, it is override.

Comment: its not css, do you meant scss or less css?

Comment: second - I think you can't override you can't things you wrote in style tag by css selectors. you should do it by jQuery or javascript

Comment: Try `.dlrsList { list-style: circle; }`

Comment: anyone please tell me, is that a valid css?

Comment: That what you're posted is not CSS, it's SCSS or SASS.

Comment: It works. Even with the `ol, ul` rule: http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/VfchC/ . Your question is UN-clear.

Answer (score 1):

This could be SASS or SCSS or LESS, but it's not CSS. This won't work unless it is run through a preprocessor.

If you want straight CSS you can't nest your selectors like that.

**EDIT**

Since there is a variable in there, I have to assume the OP is knowingly using a preprocessor.  Assuming his variable `@bldTxt` = `bold` then the resulting CSS is this:

```
.dlrs {
    width: 630px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px
}

.dlrs #listItems {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block
}

.dlrs #listItems span {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 16px;
    left: 20px
}

.dlrs #listItems #dlrsList {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify
}

.dlrs #listItems #dlrsList #itmDlrName {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: disc;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    max-width: 160px;
    font-size: 12px
}
```

Assuming that CSS, the `list-style-type : disc;` just needs to be moved to `.dlrs #listItems #dlrsList`, not in `.dlrs #listItems #dlrsList #itemDlrName`

Comment: I totally agree with you. But this is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

In your css you have `list-type:disc` try

```
#dlrsList {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Using an id will easily be enough specificity to apply the style.

### Update

You need to add an id to the `ul` at the moment `dlrslist` is set as a class.  This is why your styles are not getting picked up.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="dlrslist">
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#dlrsList {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

### Final Update

You need to set `list-style-type:disc` on the `ul` and not the `li`

```
#dlrsList {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

**Not**

```
#dlrsList {
    #itmDlrName {
        list-style-type: disc;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry its typing mistake in the question its corrected now, i have list-style-type only it didn't work either

Comment: Can you please make sure you example code is correct before posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
list-style-type: disc !important;
```

use  `!important` to overwrite css

Comment: are you sure you can override styles in style attribute?

Comment: whenever possible, do not use `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of ids:

HTML:

```
<ul class="dlrsList">
    <li class="itmDlrName">Crosstown Auto Centre</li>
    <li class="itmDlrName">Dartmouth Chrysler Jeep Dodge</li>
    <li class="itmDlrName">Grande Prairie Chrysler Jeep Dodge</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.dlrsList {
    ...
    list-style-type: disc; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **!important** approach suggested by Ankit Agrawal, or you can move your css code right after the **ol, ul { list-style-type: none; }** code. This way, it would be your css which overrides the code which is the source of your problem.

I prefer the second option, the use of **!important** should be avoid whenever possible.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with your code? It would be easy to everyone to help you.

Comment: I've just seen a problem in your code. Your **ul** has a class called **dlrsList**, not an id. Try to change your css from **#dlrsList** to **.dlrsList**

Comment: its mistake by the time i typed its id actually, sorry

Answer (score 0):

try

```
li { list-style-type: none !important; }
```

Note ive changed your ul, to li 
The !important, will force it as you already know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. try this

```
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

.dlrsList { list-style-type: disc; }
```

or just remove `ol, ul { list-style-type: none; }` from CSS and if you have more lists on your site than give each list appropriate CSS property for `list-style-type`.